# How to replace dates out of range with valid dates in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I've got a data set with 10,000 entries, one variable among others is the birthday. All the entries are unique. I noticed that about 200 entries have 1/1/1900 as birthday. The next frequent date only has a frequency of 4 and the date also doesn't make any sense in this data set. I reckon 1/1/1900 was used as a placeholder since the birthday couldn't be left empty. Long story short, I want to replace the dates of these entries with valid dates using the backfill method.

I changed the column with the birthday to a datetime object:

```
df['Client Birthdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Client Birthdate'], yearfirst=True)
```

I then tried to use:

```
timestamp = pd.Timestamp(year=1900, month=1, day=1)
df['Client Birthdate'] = df['Client Birthdate'].replace(to_replace=timestamp, method='bfill')
```

However, df['Client Birthdate'].describe() still gave me this as output:

```
[198 rows x 9 columns]
count                   10000
unique                   7897
top       1900-01-01 00:00:00
freq                      198
first     1900-01-01 00:00:00
last      1999-12-30 00:00:00
Name: Client Birthdate, dtype: object
```

So I tried using:

```
df['Client Birthdate'] = df['Client Birthdate'].replace(to_replace=timestamp, value=False)
df['Client Birthdate'] = df['Client Birthdate'].fillna(method='bfill')
```

which gave me:

```
[198 rows x 9 columns]
count     10000
unique     7897
top       False
freq        198
Name: Client Birthdate, dtype: object
```

I have no idea why replace/fillna doesn't work, are they not compatible with datetime objects?
Is there also a way to replace all dates 'out-of-range', let's say birthdays before 1920 and after 2001 with valid dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also tried replacing and I think the problem is because of matching with regexes, in any case you can solve with :

```
df["Client Birthday"].loc[df["Client Birthday"].eq(timestamp)] = np.nan
df["Client Birthday"] = df["Client Birthday"].bfill()
```

I assigned `NaT` (not a time) where "Client Birthday" is equal to the `timestamp` variable and then used `bfill` on the series.

As for your second problem, you can use [pandas between time](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) and create a range of acceptable dates. Then, if anything falls out of the range you can fill the values or replace them with something more sensible.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to make a simple dataframe:

```
df_dict = {
'Client Birthdate': '1/1/1900'
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(ddict, index=[i for i in range(len(ddict))])
```

Calling df:

```
  Client Birthdate
0         1/1/1900
```

Then, used `infer_datetime_format` within pd.to_datetime():

```
df['Client Birthdate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Client Birthdate'], infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Output of calling df again:

```
  Client Birthdate
0       1900-01-01
```

And, dtypes:

```
Client Birthdate    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

However, to get the hour-minute-second-microsecond result into your column, you have to know and set the format using strftime().  Here's a simple example:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Client Birthdate'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
```

Output:

```
0    1900-01-01 00:00:00.000000
Name: Client Birthdate, dtype: object
```

# Finally, to update your dates, just subsection the dataframe and set it equal to the date that you want.  This example uses .loc() since pandas will probably through a SettingWithCopyWarning error otherwise.

```
df.loc[df['Client Birthdate'] == '1/1/1900', :] = timestamp
```